# Reversible function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates, inverse-function

I need help.
For which $(r, θ, φ) ∈ \mathbb{R}^3$ is the function 
$$f(r,\theta,\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}x(r,\theta,\varphi)\\ y(r,\theta,\varphi)\\z(r,\theta,\varphi)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r\sin \theta\cos \varphi \\ r\sin \theta \sin \varphi \\ r\cos \theta\end{pmatrix} $$

locally reversible? and calculate $(f^{-1})'(0, -7, 0)$.

Comment: Hint: try the sum of the squares of the components, and the ratios of the components "to see".

Comment: **I have calculated determinant and have $r\sin \theta$ but get the inverse I could not calculate**

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ?

Comment: **No,I did not understand what you meant**